# Automapper Many-to-Many EF Core update fails because of duplicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am using EF Core7 along with Automapper in my project. Here is an example to explain my setup:

```
class Parent
{
    A Child1 { get; set; }
    B Child2 { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [MinLength(2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";

    public virtual ICollection<A> ChildrenA { get; set; } = new Collection<A>();
    public virtual ICollection<B> ChildrenB { get; set; } = new Collection<B>();
}
```

Each object has a corresponding DTO and automapper profile.
When I use the editor in my application I create tagDTOs on child objects. The problem occurs when I try to save the modified/created entityDTO using

```
DbContext.Parents.Persist(Mapper).InsertOrUpdateAsync(parentDTO, token);
```

During mapping a new instance is created for each tag and thus when it tries to attach them to ChangeTracker it throws an exception because multiple Tags with the same key are being added. How do I solve this? I was looking into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution but I still don't know what to do.

One idea was to first map the DTO to Parent and then manually replace all the duplicates, but that would be very complicated and require a ton of maintenace (my real objects are much more complex than the sample I provided).

Edit: Here is my initialization of Mapper in dependency injection:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper((serviceProvider, automapper) =>
{
    automapper.AddCollectionMappers();
    automapper.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<ApplicationDbContext>(serviceProvider);
}, typeof(Program));
```

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Already did but I do not see anything that would help. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Perhaps spend some time looking at the docs and the tests. That's working code.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu The mapper does run without a problem but the resulting object will have multiple tags with the same key. Could my profile be to blame?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, though it took a lot of work. First I had to modify `AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFramework` library's class `Persistence` and interface `IPersistence` to support passing options like the Map method does. Then I passed in my DbContext and configured my profile like this:

```
CreateMap<Tag, TagDTOTiny>().PreserveReferences().ReverseMap().ConstructUsing((tagDTO, resolutionContext) =>
{
    var context = resolutionContext.Items["context"] as ApplicationDbContext ?? throw new NotImplementedException("Please supply dbcontext to resolve tags!");
    var tag = context.Tags.Find(tagDTO.Name);
    if (tag is null)
    {
        tag = new() { Name = tagDTO.Name };
        context.Add(tag);
    }
    return tag;
}).PreserveReferences();
```

This code makes the Automapper first search for an existing tag, and if not found creates a new one and crucially, adds it as a tracked entity. Now everything seems to be working. I already made a PR in case the maintainers decide this would be useful for others to have.